# Nested loops in R taking too long

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, optimization, cluster-analysis

I'm have tried to do a Kernel K-Means algorithm in R manually but my loop is taking more than 30 minutes to run, here's the code:

```
#Calculanting kernel k-means
rbfkmeans<-function(data,c,q=0.02,L=0.7){ 
        #associating random classifications to each observation
        iter=0
        data<-data%>%
                mutate(cluster=sample(1:c,nrow(data),replace=T))

        mini=rep(1,nrow(data))

        ## DISTÂNCIA EUCLIDIANA  
        # Remember: 
        #1.|| a || = sqrt(aDOTa), 
        #2. d(x,y) = || x - y || = sqrt((x-y)DOT(x-y))
        #3. aDOTb = sum(a*b)


        d<-function(x,y){
                aux=x-y
                dis=sqrt(sum(aux*aux))
                return(dis)
        }

        ##Radial Basis Function Kernel
        # Remember :
        # 1.K(x,x')=exp(-q||x-x'||^2) where ||x-x'|| is could be defined as the
        # euclidian distance and 'q' it's the gamma parameter
        rbf<-function(x,y,q=0.2){
                aux<-d(x,y)
                rbfd<-exp(-q*(aux)^2)
                return(rbfd)
        }
        #
        #calculating the kernel matrix
        kernelmatrix=matrix(0,nrow(data),nrow(data))
        for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
                for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
                        kernelmatrix[i,j]=rbf(data[i,1:(ncol(data)-1)],data[j,1:(ncol(data)-1)],q)
                }
        }
        r=rep(0,nrow(data))
        distance=matrix(0,nrow(data),c)
        while(  (sum(r==data[,'cluster'])!=nrow(data)) && iter <30 ){   
                ans=0

                #Calculating the distaces in the kernelized versions (RBF example)
                print('running')
                third=rep(0,c)#here third means the calculation from centers distances
                #as they not depend of each obserativion.
                for(g in 1:c){
                        ans=0
                        for(k in 1:nrow(data)){
                                for(l in 1:nrow(data)){
                                        ans = ans + (data[k,'cluster']==g)*(data[l,'cluster']==g)*kernelmatrix[k,l]

                                }
                        }
                        third[g]=ans
                }      
                for (ii in 1:nrow(data)){       #for (ii in 1:nrow(data))
                        for(j in 1:c)  {          #for(j in 1:c)
                                distance[ii,j]= kernelmatrix[ii,ii]-2*sum((data[,'cluster']==j)*kernelmatrix[ii,])/sum(data[,'cluster']==j)+third[j]/(sum(data[,'cluster']==j)^2)
                        }
                }
                r=data[,'cluster']
                #Checking the shortest distance
                for(k in 1:nrow(data)){
                        data[k,'cluster']=match(min(distance[k,]),distance[k,])
                        mini[k]=min(distance[k,])
                }  
                plot(data[1:(ncol(data)-1)], col=data$cluster)
                iter=iter+1  
                print(paste('Iteration number:',iter))
                print(paste('Mean of min. distances:',mean(mini)))

                #print(g==data$'cluster')
        }

        return(data)
}
```

Someone have any idea how i can optmize this? The main problem it's the calculation of the #third term,  I guess that it's wasting too much time with the verification of `(data[k,'cluster']==g)` inside the loops, but I dont have more ideas to improve that...

OBS: The `data[k,'cluster']==g`, its to verify if the observation belongs to the cluster.

EDIT: The part of the code that is taking long time to run its this:

```
for(g in 1:c){
                            ans=0
                            for(k in 1:nrow(data)){
                                    for(l in 1:nrow(data)){
                                            ans = ans + (data[k,'cluster']==g)*(data[l,'cluster']==g)*kernelmatrix[k,l]

                                    }
                            }
                            third[g]=ans
                    }
```

Comment: Hi Mateus, a reproducible example of your code (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) will help us answering you.

Comment: See also [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The R interpreter *is* very slow. Rewrite critical code parts in a C library instead. Avoid the use of any kind of interpreter loop. Try to use vectorised operations, because the loops hidden in there will usually run in C or Fortran - much faster than R loops.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can optimize your distance and radial function.
Your distance gets the sqrt of the sum, bur your radial function squares it negating it

```
    d<-function(x,y){
          aux=x-y
          sum(aux*aux)
    }

    ##Radial Basis Function Kernel
    # Remember :
    # 1.K(x,x')=exp(-q||x-x'||^2) where ||x-x'|| is could be defined as the
    # euclidian distance and 'q' it's the gamma parameter
    rbf<-function(x,y,q=0.2){
            aux<-d(x,y)
            rbfd<-exp(-q*(aux))
            return(rbfd)
    }
```

Also you should be able to use convert your code to use foreach loops and the be able to take advantage of one of the parallelization libraries (such as doparallel)